# php sort array by custom defined array order

Tags: php, sorting

I have array as result from postgres database and i want to sort in order defined by data like this:

```
$order = array(77082, 77083, 77084, 77085, 77086, 77087, 77088, 77089, 77090, 77091, 77092, 77093, 77094, 77095, 77096, 77097, 77098, 77099, 77100, 77101);
```

array:

```
array(
    array("id" => 77083, "title" => "Test"),
    array("id" => 77081, "title" => "Test") ...
);
```

to array:

```
array(
    array("id" => 77081, "title" => "Test"),
    array("id" => 77083, "title" => "Test") ...
);
```

somehow to sort array in order by $order array IDs.

**Next Example:**
$order = array(77082, 65666, 90555, 35000);

array:

```
array(
    array("id" => 35000, "title" => "Test3"),
    array("id" => 65666, "title" => "Test1")
    array("id" => 77082, "title" => "Test")
    array("id" => 90555, "title" => "Test2")
);
```

to array:

```
array(
    array("id" => 77082, "title" => "Test"),
    array("id" => 65666, "title" => "Test1")
    array("id" => 90555, "title" => "Test2")
    array("id" => 35000, "title" => "Test3")
);
```

Comment: [Must check reference about php arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127)

Comment: Can't you let it sort directly in the database?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: everyone mark as duplicate no one tried to understand how the problem is different then others.

Comment: You tell us how your problem differs. Your case *is* covered in the duplicate. If you have tried to apply the techniques listed there but cannot get it to work, detail *how* it doesn't work for you.

Comment: there is no question in stack-overflow related to order by predefined order instead sorting ascending or descending

Comment: Obviously you have not even read the duplicate.

Comment: BTW, your order *is* simply ascending.

Comment: in example that i add yes ill add one more example that i need.